# Point Cloud Symbol in a PGFplot legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a point cloud of data in a plot, and a reviewer commented on changing the legend entry for the point cloud from a single dot to a point cloud like or at least a few dots in the legend. However I have no clue as to how to achieve this. I am aware that I can change the legend entries, but how would you as to change the symbol to have multiple points?

As an example the MWE
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
small,
height=3in,
axis equal image,
xmin=-0.3,
xmax=0.3,
y dir=reverse,
ymin=-1.15,
ymax=1.12,
name=plot1,
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left,at={(axis cs:0.35,0)},anchor=west,font=\footnotesize}
]
\addplot+[
only marks,
mark=*,
mark size = 0.2pt,
mark options={solid}
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.0828301519283208 -0.973246408029514\\
0.0716818671371936 -0.962098123238387\\
0.0716818671371936 -0.95094983844726\\
0.0605335823460664 -0.939801553656133\\
0.0605335823460664 -0.928653268865005\\
0.0493852975549392 -0.917504984073878\\
0.0493852975549392 -0.906356699282751\\
0.038237012763812 -0.895208414491624\\
0.038237012763812 -0.884060129700497\\
0.0270887279726848 -0.872911844909369\\
0.0270887279726848 -0.861763560118242\\
0.0270887279726848 -0.850615275327115\\
};
\addlegendentry{contour points};


\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you mean some symbol like `$\dblcolon$` of package `mathtools` or `$\because$` of `amssymb`?

Comment: @Fran not really, more sth like dispersed points indicating the point cloud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a preliminary solution. I hope to generalize it by: setting the units of the `legend image code` to scale with the `mark size` to prevent overlapping scatter points with larger markers.

I started with the definition of `xbar legend` (p. 212 of the v1.11 `pgfplots` manual) and modified it to plot a small scattering of coordinates:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/scatter legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={\draw[##1,yshift=-0.1em] plot coordinates {
      (0.1em, 0.1em)
      (0.2em, 0.4em)
      (0.3em, 0.0em)
      (0.4em, 0.3em)
    };},
  },
}
```

This new `scatter legend` style may now be applied to either entire `axis` environments or individual `\addplot` commands.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/scatter legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={\draw[##1,yshift=-0.1em] plot coordinates {
      (0.1em, 0.1em)
      (0.2em, 0.4em)
      (0.3em, 0.0em)
      (0.4em, 0.3em)
    };},
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[scatter legend]
  \addplot+[only marks,mark=*,mark size = 0.5pt,mark options={solid}] 
    table[row sep=crcr] {
      0.0828301519283208 -0.973246408029514\\
      0.0716818671371936 -0.962098123238387\\
    };
  \addlegendentry{contour points1};
  \addplot+[only marks,mark=*,mark size = 0.5pt,mark options={solid}] 
    table[row sep=crcr] {
      0.0716818671371936 -0.95094983844726\\
      0.0605335823460664 -0.939801553656133\\
    };
  \addlegendentry{contour points2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer this solution as it allows me to customize the legend image, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use `pattern=crosshatch dots` for the legend via

```
\pgfplotsset{
    legend image code/.code={%
        \draw[pattern=crosshatch dots, pattern color=blue, draw=none] 
                (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.3cm,0.1cm);
    }
}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfplotsset{
    legend image code/.code={%
        \draw[pattern=crosshatch dots, pattern color=blue, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.3cm,0.1cm);
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
small,
height=3in,
axis equal image,
xmin=-0.3,
xmax=0.3,
y dir=reverse,
ymin=-1.15,
ymax=1.12,
name=plot1,
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left,at={(axis cs:0.35,0)},anchor=west,font=\footnotesize}
]
\addplot+[
only marks,
mark=*,
mark size = 0.2pt,
mark options={solid}
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.0828301519283208 -0.973246408029514\\
0.0716818671371936 -0.962098123238387\\
0.0716818671371936 -0.95094983844726\\
0.0605335823460664 -0.939801553656133\\
0.0605335823460664 -0.928653268865005\\
0.0493852975549392 -0.917504984073878\\
0.0493852975549392 -0.906356699282751\\
0.038237012763812 -0.895208414491624\\
0.038237012763812 -0.884060129700497\\
0.0270887279726848 -0.872911844909369\\
0.0270887279726848 -0.861763560118242\\
0.0270887279726848 -0.850615275327115\\
};
\addlegendentry{contour points};


\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```